# Can I give a generic function the correct type information?

Tags: java, generics, dependent-type

I have a bunch of class properties that are initialized in a somewhat complicated but very uniform way.  Since it is both error prone and a pain to maintain about 10 copies of this code I would like to abstract this.

Here is what the code looks like for setting one property:

```java
if ( userConfigMapPath != null ) {
    final TypeReference<UserConfig> ref =
            new TypeReference<UserConfig>() {
            };
    this.userConfig = Optional.of(
            new GenericConfigMap<>( userConfigMapPath, (int) REFRESH_RATE.getSeconds(), objectMapper, ref ) );
} else {
    this.userConfig = Optional.empty();
}
```

This is repeated for each property, except with differing property names (in this case `userConfig`), path (`userConfigMapPath`) and type (`userConfigMap`).

So I try abstracting it into a method.

```java
    private <T> Optional<GenericConfigMap<T>> optionalGenericConfigMapFromPath( final ObjectMapper objectMapper, final String path ) {
        Optional<GenericConfigMap<T>> result;
        if ( path != null ) {
            final TypeReference<T> ref =
                    new TypeReference<T>( ) {
                    };
            result = Optional.of(
                    new GenericConfigMap<>( path, (int) REFRESH_RATE.getSeconds( ), objectMapper, ref ) );
        } else {
            result = Optional.empty( );
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Note that since the type of each property is different this function is generic.  I use this method to set each property:

```java
this.userConfig = optionalGenericConfigMapFromPath(objectMapper, userConfigMapPath);
this.networkConfig = optionalGenericConfigMapFromPath(objectMapper, networkConfigMapPath);
this.dodadConfig = optionalGenericConfigMapFromPath(objectMapper, dodadConfigMapPath);
```

Now this *compiles* however it has some serious runtime issues.  The crux of the issue is that the compiler seems unable to determine what `T` is in any of the above cases.  It seems to base its selection of `T` based on the default of the object mapper instead of the type of the property.  And since the object mapper is reading from json this makes for a `LinkedHashMap` instead of any type we want.

Now this doesn't cause a compile error, something that baffles me, but instead produces an exception any time we try to use a method from one of these properties we get a runtime type error (could not cast `LinkedHashMap` to the actual type).

What I want is for the compiler to actually know at compile time the type of `T` for each call to the function. In fact I would be perfectly happy to tell it the type of `T` if it would let me.  Using this syntax that @JeroenSteenbeeke helped me with

```java
this.userConfig = this.<UserConfig> optionalGenericConfigMapFromPath(objectMapper, userConfigMapPath);
this.networkConfig = this.<NetworkConfig> optionalGenericConfigMapFromPath(objectMapper, networkConfigMapPath);
this.doodadConfig = this.<DoodadConfig> optionalGenericConfigMapFromPath(objectMapper, doodadConfigMapPath);
```

This type information seems to have just been ignored since when I run the debugger it still behaves exactly as it did. So I tried some janky dependent typing using `Class` as a proxy:

```java
    private <T> Optional<GenericConfigMap<T>> optionalGenericConfigMapFromPath( final Class<T>, final ObjectMapper objectMapper, final String path ) {
        Optional<GenericConfigMap<T>> result;
        if ( path != null ) {
            final TypeReference<T> ref =
                    new TypeReference<T>( ) {
                    };
            result = Optional.of(
                    new GenericConfigMap<>( path, (int) REFRESH_RATE.getSeconds( ), objectMapper, ref ) );
        } else {
            result = Optional.empty( );
        }
        return result;
    }
```

```java
this.userConfig = optionalGenericConfigMapFromPath( UserConfig.class, objectMapper, userConfigMapPath);
this.networkConfig = optionalGenericConfigMapFromPath( NetworkConfig.class, objectMapper, networkConfigMapPath);
this.doodadConfig = optionalGenericConfigMapFromPath( DoodadConfig.class, objectMapper, doodadConfigMapPath);
```

This is basically the dependent function type:

[image: Dependent type]

The compiler also ignores the type information given in this example and continues to produce the same incorrectly typed programs as before.

I'm really at my wits end with this.  ***Is there any way to get the compiler to recognize this type information and create values of the correct types?***

Comment: I would recommend reading about type erasure in Java: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html, this should provide some enlightenment regarding the difficulties you're having. That said, I think that what you're trying to may still be possible, though you might need to add an argument of type `Class<T>` to your methods, that way you can say something like `UserConfig userConfig = optionalGenericConfigMapFromPath(UserConfig.class, objectMapper, userConfigMapPath);`

Comment: @JeroenSteenbeeke Thanks for the read.  It was pretty enlightening.  I had a more aggressive model of type erasure in mind so the behaviour makes more sense now.  The adding of `Class<T>` seems to be a more sane way of doing my proxy based example.  And unless I am misinterpreting you it ends up unfortunately yielding the same result.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a compiler bug at all, it's just a result of how Jackson implements `TypeReference` (although I suppose it's caused by a limitation of Java).

When you write `new TypeReference<T>() {};`, the compiler rewrites that to something like `new Foo$1();` where `Foo` is the name of the class your method is in. The generated anonymous class looks something like this. Note that if `T` is a type parameter to another method, the argument to `TypeReference` is a special `Type` that refers back to the original type parameter `T`.

```
class Foo$1 extends TypeReference<T> {}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZVHBaoNAED3Hrxg87Tat9NwkltDSngqlCb2EHEbdyKbrKuuYkojfbmdVSKALrrvvvXnzmD3iCR@O2U/f66IqHcGRgcigzSOnDkalFN0tgluuIW08FlRNYnQKqcG6hg/UFtpgNoE1IfHvVOoMCqbEhpy2@W4P6PJaeuXsrSzhwN8KrPoFvgm5YJihaDnKYz6LMMFL6Jku6IJg7OZL2wB4Lbfx2MVLt0Bywv3aniv1pQ6QoJuaTAgXCdl27PmJDgtFyumLyjwLdcPbCsQ/RnqfKFf04iMI6Y/vyrIg3XCNS0eYTb36G53GxKjlcwx0Hi1vcTk08h7rlBo0nlu7vCmUJXbZPe7ZaHOuSRVR2VBU8TzIWBEOIS1He4IQ5qP3HMJ7yBQncCoDpCt1E/J14PlZSiskx/QTGkaKSU0OU5pe8jojaLu@/wM) and/or look at it in [Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(filename:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:java,selection:(endColumn:2,endLineNumber:7,positionColumn:2,positionLineNumber:7,selectionStartColumn:2,selectionStartLineNumber:7,startColumn:2,startLineNumber:7),source:%27class+Foo%3CR%3E+%7B%0A++++%3CT%3E+Bar%3CT%3E+foo(T+t)+%7B%0A++++++++return+new+Bar%3CT%3E()%7B%0A++++++++++++T+foo()+%7B+return+t%3B+%7D%3B%0A++++++++%7D%3B%0A++++%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Aabstract+class+Bar%3CT%3E+%7B%0A++++abstract+T+foo()%3B%0A%7D%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27Java+source+%231%27,t:%270%27)),k:50,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:java1102,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%271%27,commentOnly:%270%27,demangle:%270%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%271%27,intel:%270%27,libraryCode:%270%27,trim:%271%27),flagsViewOpen:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:java,libs:!(),options:%27%27,selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:1,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:1,tree:%271%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27jdk+11.0.2+(Java,+Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),k:50,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4).

The `TypeReference` [constructor](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-core/blob/2.13/src/main/java/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/type/TypeReference.java#L31) looks something like this:

```
protected TypeReference() {
  Type superClass = getClass().getGenericSuperclass();
  //_type is the type to construct. It should be UserConfig.class, DoodadConfig.class, etc.
  _type = ((ParameterizedType) superClass).getActualTypeArguments()[0];
}
```

So if the `T` above is a concrete type like `UserConfig`, everything's hunky-dory. `getClass()` will give you `Foo$1.class`, `getGenericSuperclass()` will give you a type representing `TypeReference<UserConfig>`, and `_type` will be `UserConfig.class`. Later on, when Jackson is reading an object, it sees that you want a `UserConfig` and not a `LinkedHashMap`, so it uses reflection to look at `UserConfig` and construct an object of that class.

However, if `T` is a type parameter, `_type` will be a [`TypeVariable`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/reflect/TypeVariable.html). Unfortunately, this `TypeVariable` cannot yield any information about what `T`'s actual value was, at least as far as I can tell. This is because there is only one anonymous class that is generated, even if there are multiple instances of it. Since Java doesn't do monomorphization, all the `TypeReference<T>`s you create in your `optionalGenericConfigMapFromPath` method will be instances of the same exact class: `Foo$1`. The superclass of that is `TypeReference<T>`, which is erased to `TypeReference<Object>` because it's impossible for that `T` to point to every single `XConfig` class you have.

Because Jackson doesn't have any information about which class you want to construct an instance of, it just defaults to using a `LinkedHashMap`. Since that's obviously not the same as, say, `UserConfig`, you get a `ClassCastException` or something of that sort at runtime.

The compiler does infer the types correctly, but even if it didn't, it wouldn't matter because of the wacky way type erasure is handled. Since Jackson makes heavy use of reflection, these sort of weird things are probably more likely to happen. It's best if you pass either a `TypeReference<T>` or a `Class<T>` to the `optionalGenericConfigMapFromPath` method itself. You *are* already passing a `Class`, but even if it affected type inference, it's useless for the runtime stuff, so you'll have to give it as an argument to `GenericConfigMap` instead of `ref`, assuming that `GenericConfigMap`'s constructor takes any `Type`, not just `TypeReference`s.

Answer (score 0):

The reason this fails is that the `TypeReference` doesn't capture the `T` at the method's call site, because it can't see the method's call site.

You pass in the `Class<T>` as a parameter (but I think it is unused, at least, you've not named it, so I can't see where it is used). Instead, pass in the `TypeReference<T>` at the call site (e.g. `new TypeReference<UserConfig>() {}`), and don't try to construct it in the method.